awk merging files where col value is in range
I have a tab delim dataset1
NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
NC_044998.1     31388   68748   DCBLD2
NC_044998.1     80874   299341  CMSS1
NC_044998.1     112495  297570  FILIP1L
NC_044998.1     287349  289742  LOC116808959
NC_044998.1     300404  343805  TBC1D23
NC_044998.1     333622  344667  NIT2
NC_044998.1     346168  368957  TOMM70
NC_044998.1     371654  380427  LNP1
NC_044998.1     387231  413422  TMEM45A

and another tab delim dataset2
1       NC_044998.1     15001   6.040368        2.038993e-04
1       NC_044998.1     25002   0.000000        3.333334e-01
1       NC_044998.1     35003   2.309260        4.638924e-03
1       NC_044998.1     45004   3.438428        5.053365e-03
1       NC_044998.1     55005   1.086369        9.663565e-02
1       NC_044998.1     65006   3.250019        8.298793e-04
1       NC_044998.1     75007   1.081163        8.039542e-03
1       NC_044998.1     85008   0.186722        8.158607e-02
1       NC_044998.1     95009   2.236803        3.256445e-03
1       NC_044998.1     105010  0.089978        2.846438e-01

I want to do for each line of dataset2 if string in col 2 of dataset2 matches string in col1 of dataset1 and value in col 3 of dataset2 is between values in col2 and col3 of dataset1, print line of dataset2 followed by line of dataset1, else print line of dataset2 followed by "." in each column.
Im using
NR==FNR {
    q[++n] = $0
    f1[n] = $2
    f2[n] = $3
    next
}
# process file2
{
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if ($1 == f1[i] && (f2[i] > $2 && f2[i] < $3))
            print q[i]"\t"$0
        else
            print q[i]"\t"".""\t"".""\t"".""\t""."
    }
} 

but it's not working, as it just prints whichever file is first followed by the dot columns
awk -f annot.sh dataset2 dataset1

1       NC_044998.1     15001   6.040368        2.038993e-04    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     25002   0.000000        3.333334e-01    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     35003   2.309260        4.638924e-03    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     45004   3.438428        5.053365e-03    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     55005   1.086369        9.663565e-02    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     65006   3.250019        8.298793e-04    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     75007   1.081163        8.039542e-03    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     85008   0.186722        8.158607e-02    .       .       .       .       .
1       NC_044998.1     95009   2.236803        3.256445e-03    .       .       .       .       .
1       NC_044998.1     105010  0.089978        2.846438e-01    .       .       .       .       .

the expected output is
1       NC_044998.1     15001   6.040368        2.038993e-04    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     25002   0.000000        3.333334e-01    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     35003   2.309260        4.638924e-03    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     35003   2.309260        4.638924e-03    NC_044998.1     31388   68748   DCBLD2
1       NC_044998.1     45004   3.438428        5.053365e-03    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     45004   3.438428        5.053365e-03    NC_044998.1     31388   68748   DCBLD2
1       NC_044998.1     55005   1.086369        9.663565e-02    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     55005   1.086369        9.663565e-02    NC_044998.1     31388   68748   DCBLD2
1       NC_044998.1     65006   3.250019        8.298793e-04    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     65006   3.250019        8.298793e-04    NC_044998.1     31388   68748   DCBLD2
1       NC_044998.1     75007   1.081163        8.039542e-03    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     85008   0.186722        8.158607e-02    NC_044998.1     80874   299341  CMSS1
1       NC_044998.1     95009   2.236803        3.256445e-03    NC_044998.1     80874   299341  CMSS1
1       NC_044998.1     105010  0.089978        2.846438e-01    NC_044998.1     80874   299341  CMSS1


please update the question with a) the (wrong) output generated by your code and b) the (correct) expected output; also indicate the order in which you're currently feeding the files to awk

will all lines in both files always have the same single key value, eg, NC_044998.1 in this case?

No, the files are much bigger than the snippet, and both contain different strings at that column.

will it ever be possible for a line in dataset2 to have 2 matching lines from dataset1? in other words, can the ranges in dataset1 ever overlap?

Yes they overlap, in 1       NC_044998.1     15001   6.040368        2.038993e-04, 15001 is between 14582   and  80739, in NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041. So it should print NC_044998.1     15001   6.040368        2.038993e-04 NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041.

ok, so there are overlaps in dataset1 ... good to know but ... will it ever be possible for a row from dataset2 to find 2 matching rows from dataset1? and if the answer is 'yes' then which row from dataset1 should be displayed?

I have GNU awk and am using a computer cluster at the University, so no prob there. Thank you!

I added a correct output snippet

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

why don't each of (dataset2) 35003, 45004, 55005 and 65006 match on the two rows (dataset1) 14582 / 80739 and 31388 / 68748? (this comes back to the question I've asked a couple times ... can a row from dataset2 have more than one match from dataset1

@MadzaFarias-Virgens Your first file is in bed format. The second file can be converted to bed format. The bed file operations can be easily carried out using bedtools package. It can be installed using conda.

Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates all your requirements and we can copy/paste to test with. That'll be input files with multiple key values in each file, not just NC_044998.1 everywhere, some key values present in both files, some just in the first file, some in the second, and some cases where there are values in ranges, and some where there aren't.

Using any awk:
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR == FNR {
    cnts[$1]++
    begs[$1,cnts[$1]] = $2
    ends[$1,cnts[$1]] = $3
    vals[$1,cnts[$1]] = $0
    gsub("[^"FS"]+",".")
    dflt = $0
    next
}
{
    val = dflt
    if ( $2 in cnts ) {
        for ( i=1; i<=cnts[$2]; i++ ) {
            if ( (begs[$2,i] <= $3) && ($3 <= ends[$2,i]) ) {
                val = vals[$2,i]
                break
            }
        }
    }
    print $0, val
}


$ awk -f tst.awk dataset1 dataset2
1       NC_044998.1     15001   6.040368        2.038993e-04    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     25002   0.000000        3.333334e-01    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     35003   2.309260        4.638924e-03    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     45004   3.438428        5.053365e-03    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     55005   1.086369        9.663565e-02    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     65006   3.250019        8.298793e-04    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     75007   1.081163        8.039542e-03    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     85008   0.186722        8.158607e-02    NC_044998.1     80874   299341  CMSS1
1       NC_044998.1     95009   2.236803        3.256445e-03    NC_044998.1     80874   299341  CMSS1
1       NC_044998.1     105010  0.089978        2.846438e-01    NC_044998.1     80874   299341  CMSS1

The above is assuming that the first match to a range is all that's required. If you do want all matches printed then change it to:
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR == FNR {
    cnts[$1]++
    begs[$1,cnts[$1]] = $2
    ends[$1,cnts[$1]] = $3
    vals[$1,cnts[$1]] = $0
    gsub("[^"FS"]+",".")
    dflt = $0
    next
}
{
    found = 0
    if ( $2 in cnts ) {
        for ( i=1; i<=cnts[$2]; i++ ) {
            if ( (begs[$2,i] <= $3) && ($3 <= ends[$2,i]) ) {
                print $0, vals[$2,i]
                found = 1
            }
        }
    }
    if ( !found ) {
        print $0, dflt
    }
}


$ awk -f tst.awk dataset1 dataset2
1       NC_044998.1     15001   6.040368        2.038993e-04    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     25002   0.000000        3.333334e-01    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     35003   2.309260        4.638924e-03    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     35003   2.309260        4.638924e-03    NC_044998.1     31388   68748   DCBLD2
1       NC_044998.1     45004   3.438428        5.053365e-03    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     45004   3.438428        5.053365e-03    NC_044998.1     31388   68748   DCBLD2
1       NC_044998.1     55005   1.086369        9.663565e-02    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     55005   1.086369        9.663565e-02    NC_044998.1     31388   68748   DCBLD2
1       NC_044998.1     65006   3.250019        8.298793e-04    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     65006   3.250019        8.298793e-04    NC_044998.1     31388   68748   DCBLD2
1       NC_044998.1     75007   1.081163        8.039542e-03    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     85008   0.186722        8.158607e-02    NC_044998.1     80874   299341  CMSS1
1       NC_044998.1     95009   2.236803        3.256445e-03    NC_044998.1     80874   299341  CMSS1
1       NC_044998.1     105010  0.089978        2.846438e-01    NC_044998.1     80874   299341  CMSS1


This seems to work correctly and quickly. If this paper does come out someday, I'll make sure to thank you for your help with writing and running awk scripts in the acknowledgments section!

Yet an other solution with GNU awk. As you don't have RAM limitations then let's slurp the whole dataset1 into a multi-dim array, then search and output each matching range:
awk -v OFS='\t' '
    BEGIN { PROCINFO["@ind_num_asc"] }
    FNR == NR {
        if (FNR == 1)
            for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
                empty1 = (empty1 ? empty1 OFS "." : ".")
        records1[$1][FNR]["min"]  = $2+0
        records1[$1][FNR]["max"]  = $3+0
        records1[$1][FNR]["line"] = $0
        next
    }
    {
        found = 0
        if ($2 in records1) {
            val = $3+0
            for (fnr1 in records1[$2]) {
                min = records1[$2][fnr1]["min"]
                max = records1[$2][fnr1]["max"]
                if (min < val && val < max) {
                    print $0, records1[$2][fnr1]["line"]
                    found = 1
                    #break
                }
            }
        }
        if (!found)
            print $0, empty1
    }
' dataset1 dataset2

note: If you just need the first match then uncomment the break that is after the found = 1
output:
1   NC_044998.1 15001   6.040368    2.038993e-04    NC_044998.1 14582   80739   LOC100221041
1   NC_044998.1 25002   0.000000    3.333334e-01    NC_044998.1 14582   80739   LOC100221041
1   NC_044998.1 35003   2.309260    4.638924e-03    NC_044998.1 14582   80739   LOC100221041
1   NC_044998.1 35003   2.309260    4.638924e-03    NC_044998.1 31388   68748   DCBLD2
1   NC_044998.1 45004   3.438428    5.053365e-03    NC_044998.1 14582   80739   LOC100221041
1   NC_044998.1 45004   3.438428    5.053365e-03    NC_044998.1 31388   68748   DCBLD2
1   NC_044998.1 55005   1.086369    9.663565e-02    NC_044998.1 14582   80739   LOC100221041
1   NC_044998.1 55005   1.086369    9.663565e-02    NC_044998.1 31388   68748   DCBLD2
1   NC_044998.1 65006   3.250019    8.298793e-04    NC_044998.1 14582   80739   LOC100221041
1   NC_044998.1 65006   3.250019    8.298793e-04    NC_044998.1 31388   68748   DCBLD2
1   NC_044998.1 75007   1.081163    8.039542e-03    NC_044998.1 14582   80739   LOC100221041
1   NC_044998.1 85008   0.186722    8.158607e-02    NC_044998.1 80874   299341  CMSS1
1   NC_044998.1 95009   2.236803    3.256445e-03    NC_044998.1 80874   299341  CMSS1
1   NC_044998.1 105010  0.089978    2.846438e-01    NC_044998.1 80874   299341  CMSS1


how about using bedtools which is the de-facto bioinformatics tool for handling intervals . It needs reformatting but the command could be something like:
bedtools intersect -b <(cat dataset1.bed ) -a <(awk '{printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",$2,int($3)-1,$3,$1,$4,$5);}' dataset2.bed ) -wa -wb -loj
NC_044998.1 15000   15001   1   6.040368    2.038993e-04    NC_044998.1 14582   80739   LOC100221041
NC_044998.1 25001   25002   1   0.000000    3.333334e-01    NC_044998.1 14582   80739   LOC100221041
NC_044998.1 35002   35003   1   2.309260    4.638924e-03    NC_044998.1 14582   80739   LOC100221041
NC_044998.1 35002   35003   1   2.309260    4.638924e-03    NC_044998.1 31388   68748   DCBLD2
NC_044998.1 45003   45004   1   3.438428    5.053365e-03    NC_044998.1 14582   80739   LOC100221041
NC_044998.1 45003   45004   1   3.438428    5.053365e-03    NC_044998.1 31388   68748   DCBLD2
NC_044998.1 55004   55005   1   1.086369    9.663565e-02    NC_044998.1 14582   80739   LOC100221041
NC_044998.1 55004   55005   1   1.086369    9.663565e-02    NC_044998.1 31388   68748   DCBLD2
NC_044998.1 65005   65006   1   3.250019    8.298793e-04    NC_044998.1 14582   80739   LOC100221041
NC_044998.1 65005   65006   1   3.250019    8.298793e-04    NC_044998.1 31388   68748   DCBLD2
NC_044998.1 75006   75007   1   1.081163    8.039542e-03    NC_044998.1 14582   80739   LOC100221041
NC_044998.1 85007   85008   1   0.186722    8.158607e-02    NC_044998.1 80874   299341  CMSS1
NC_044998.1 95008   95009   1   2.236803    3.256445e-03    NC_044998.1 80874   299341  CMSS1
NC_044998.1 105009  105010  1   0.089978    2.846438e-01    NC_044998.1 80874   299341  CMSS1


Assumptions/understandings:

for a given key (eg, NC_044998.1) in dataset1 there can be multiple rows, some with ranges ($2 - $3) that overlap
because of the range overlaps (dataset1) I'm assuming it's possible for a row from dataset2 to find more than one match from dataset1

I added the following row to dataset2 to demonstrate a non-match in dataset1:
1       NC_044998.1     999999  0.089978        2.846438e-01

One idea using GNU awk:
$ cat dataset.awk
BEGIN   { OFS = "\t"
          delete range                      # explicitly inform awk
          delete desc                       # these are arrays
        }

        # process 1st file (dataset1)

NR==FNR { range[$1][$2]=$3                  # $1 == key(NC_044998.1), $2 == low, $3 == high
          desc[$1][$2]=$4                   # $4 == description
          next
        }

        # process 2nd file (dataset2)

        { found_match = 0
          if ( $2 in range )
             for ( low in range[$2] )
                 if ( low+0 <= $3 && $3 <= range[$2][low] ) {
                    found_match = 1
                    print $0,$2,low,range[$2][low],desc[$2][low]
                 }
             if ( found_match == 0 )
                print $0,".",".",".",".","."
        }

NOTES:

multi-dimensional array support requires GNU awk
multi-dimensional arrays can use up extra memory so I'm assuming OP's dataset is not so large as to cause awk to generate an out-of-memory error
low+0 addresses an issue where awk treats low as having type string; the +0 forces awk to treat low as an number

Taking for a test drive:
$ awk -f dataset.awk dataset1 dataset2
1       NC_044998.1     15001   6.040368        2.038993e-04    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041

1       NC_044998.1     25002   0.000000        3.333334e-01    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041

1       NC_044998.1     35003   2.309260        4.638924e-03    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     35003   2.309260        4.638924e-03    NC_044998.1     31388   68748   DCBLD2

1       NC_044998.1     45004   3.438428        5.053365e-03    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     45004   3.438428        5.053365e-03    NC_044998.1     31388   68748   DCBLD2

1       NC_044998.1     55005   1.086369        9.663565e-02    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     55005   1.086369        9.663565e-02    NC_044998.1     31388   68748   DCBLD2

1       NC_044998.1     65006   3.250019        8.298793e-04    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041
1       NC_044998.1     65006   3.250019        8.298793e-04    NC_044998.1     31388   68748   DCBLD2

1       NC_044998.1     75007   1.081163        8.039542e-03    NC_044998.1     14582   80739   LOC100221041

1       NC_044998.1     85008   0.186722        8.158607e-02    NC_044998.1     80874   299341  CMSS1

1       NC_044998.1     95009   2.236803        3.256445e-03    NC_044998.1     80874   299341  CMSS1

1       NC_044998.1     105010  0.089978        2.846438e-01    NC_044998.1     80874   299341  CMSS1

1       NC_044998.1     999999  0.089978        2.846438e-01    .       .       .       .       .

NOTES:

blank lines have been added for clarity to show those instances where a row from dataset2 has more than one match from dataset1
OP's expected output does not show the dual matches; for now I'm assuming OP needs to update the expected output or provide more details on what to do when a row from dataset2 has more than one match from dataset1


Sorry, I had not realized there could be multiple matches. You are right. The one thing I noticed that is wrong with the code is that first it has to look for a match in column NC... because both files have multiple different strings in that column with overlapping ranges.

The +0s issue you mentioned would be because $3 looks numeric and so is a strnum, while low is an array index and so is a string no matter what was used to create that index. So with low <= $3 you have a string vs strnum comparison which is treated as a string comparison and therefore you need to make that low+0 <= $3 to make it number vs strnum which is a numeric comparison. You don't need any other +0s (e.g. $3 = $3 +0) since all the other values being compared are strnums and so will have a numeric comparison. That'll be true for all awks.

thanks for the confirmation/explanation; in my testing typeof() was showing the same thing you state .... low == string, $3 == strnum; for some reason $3+0 (or $3=$3+0) was sufficient to generate the desired result in my cygwin/awk 5.3.0 env, while low+0 was sufficient in both the cygwin and ubuntu/awk 5.1.0 envs; I've gone ahead and removed the $3+0 code since low+0 is sufficient in both of my envs; regards

Ah, that's actually a bug in gawk 5.3.0 where it's doing numeric instead of string comparisons when an array index that looks like a number is involved. I reported it a few weeks ago and a fix should be available in git by now, see https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2024-04/msg00000.html.
